# C++: Relative --> Absolute URL Path

Tags: c++, url, relative-path, absolute-path, relative-url

- I am given a URL string: "http://stackoverflow.com/hello/world/help/me/please/../../thanks"
- I want to return the absolute path from it: "http://stackoverflow.com/hello/world/help/thanks"

My first approach would be to count the amount of '/../' within the string, and then delete that # of /STRING/ before the last one.

However I was wondering if anyone was aware of a built-in C++ function that could help me accomplish this.

Comment: Use a ready-made library that does this work.  You are bound to miss corner cases if you attempt to write this yourself.

Comment: That approach will only work if all the `../` occurrences are next to each other.

Comment: The C++17 filesystem library supports operations like this, though you might have to apply them to only the path component (the : and // might confuse matters otherwise).

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks! Do you have any idea which operation may work?

Comment: @ShawnMorrison: That would be the [lexical transformations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/lexically_normal).